# How to put a breakpoint in a request sent through Fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

In fiddler, how to terminate the request in between before it reaches the host. For eg I send a request and I want to put a breakpoint in that request so that I'm not able to receive the response. Basically, I want to inspect the response before it is returned to the original caller and how my service is behaving if there's a connection lost or some other termination by which the request was unable to reach the server. Any answer is highly appreciated. Sorry for any flaw, I'm a newbie in using Fiddler. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiddler offers several mechanisms for interfering with requests. If your goal is to simply kill the request without returning a response, you can create a rule with an Action of ***drop** or ***reset** rules in Fiddler's AutoResponder.

`*drop` will close the client connection immediately without sending a response. The closure is graceful at the TCP/IP level, returning a FIN to the client.

`*reset` will close the client connection immediately without sending a response. The closure is abrupt at the TCP/IP level, returning a RST to the client.

Alternatively, you can have Fiddler return any HTTP/4xx or HTTP/5xx to the client.

Lastly, you could use a **breakpoint** to allow you to manually manipulate the request before it's sent to the server, and/or manipulate the server's response before it's sent to the client. Use the `bpu` command in the QuickExec box to break on a given URL (e.g. `bpu sample.asp`).

Comment: Note that `bpu` matches any URL which **contains** the text you supply to the command.